# Corda node numbers that deployed on cloud

Tags: azure, blockchain, corda

I am follow [this](https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm.html) tutorial to deploy nodes on Azure.

According to the tutorial, I can choose Number of participant nodes and Number of notary nodes.

So, is that means, all nodes are running on one machine? Can I only deploy one node on one machine? And how do I make nodes interaction with each other that are deployed on different machines?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can (and you should) have one node per VM.
2. You can join Corda TestNet for free, which will allow you to use the network's notary and network map services; allowing your nodes to talk to each other and finalize transactions.
3. The full details can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm-explore.html